# Is it a standard to add integral-microphones into motherboards?

Tags: motherboard, microphone

I came across a few motherboards that had microphones embedded inside them: I didn't need to plug in any microphone to the computer and could still record myself with programs like [Audacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audacity_(audio_editor)).

Is it some universal standard to add microphones into motherboards? If there is such a standard I assume it was accepted somewhere around the year 2010.

I ask this only out of curiosity (I'm not sure it's the best site to ask this in).

Comment: My suspicion is there likely isn't any "standard" as you might be imaging it at this point. It's very likely simply a trend in manufacturing (though, honestly, I can't say I have seen it much outside laptops designed with e.g. Skype, etc. in mind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it some universal standard to add microphones into motherboards? If
>   there is such a standard I assume it was accepted somewhere around
>   2010.

There is not a standard that would cover having a microphone embedded in a motherboard, the only reason it would be included, is because of consumer demand.